LoginForm submission which sends sign in link to email and then sets value in localStorage
My code works perfectly to send a sign in link via email, but for additional optimization I wonder can I use onSubmit with useMutation from the React Query library - is it even possible?
Code:
export const LoginForm = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [info, setInfo] = useState("");

  const onSubmit = (data: Inputs) => {
    setLoading(true);
    sendSignInLinkToEmail(auth, data.email, {
      url: "http://localhost:5173/landing",
      handleCodeInApp: true,
    })
      .then(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("email", data.email);
        setLoading(false);
        setError("");
        setInfo("Email link has been sent");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setError(error.message);
      });
  };

  return (
    <CommonForm
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      buttonText="Send Email Link"
      isPending={loading}
      isError={error}
      infoMessage={info}
    />
  );
};


useMutation can used to handle the asynchronous operation. It returns several states such as isLoading, isError, error, and isSuccess, which help in managing the UI states accordingly.mutate function triggers the mutation. In your case, it initiates the email sending process. onSuccess callback, you can handle any side effects of the mutation, such as updating local storage.

There is a slight bit of duplication in the promise callback chain:

  .then(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("email", data.email);
    setLoading(false);
    setError("");
    setInfo("Email link has been sent");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    setLoading(false);
    setError(error.message);
  });


Notice that both blocks contain setLoading(false);. That could be pulled out and put into a callback of a call to the finally method after the call to the catch method.
.finally(() => {
    setLoading(false);
}); 

